# What is /proc/net/packet?

Tags: linux, networking

In `/proc/net/tcp` I can see all tcp inodes .

In `/proc/net/udp` I can see all udp inodes .

What I can see in `/proc/net/packet` ?

Comment: all [packet(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) inodes?

Comment: btw, "all" is relative; `/proc/net` is nowadays a link to `/proc/self/net`, it only shows stuff from the current network namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints all of the current allocated AF_PACKET/PF_PACKET sockets and their information.